# How to Declare this string in java ( IF else statement )

Tags: java

```
    // rad30Deck:
    if (rad30Deck.isSelected()){
        String decksize = "30mm Wide";
    }

    // rad32Deck:
    if (rad32Deck.isSelected()){
        String decksize = "32mm Wide";
    }

    else{
       String decksize = "33.3mm Wide";
    }

    // rad30Trucks: 
    if (rad30Trucks.isSelected()){
       String decksize = "30mm Wide";
    }
    else{
       String trucksize = "32mm Wide";
    }
```

It tells me that decksize is alright, but then when I want to add it to my output it says that this variable isn't in existence..

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Java has block scope, the variables are all local to their `if` blocks. Declare it outside of the `if` clause.

Comment: I am recommending a little edit to your coding, to keep syntax within a more logical flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `String decksize = null;` outside the if statement, since currently it exists only within the if statement. The same goes for `trucksize`.

Comment: And no longer declare `decksize` and `trucksize` as a `String` inside the `if`or `else` statements (I realise you know this, but if OP asked the question, it's probably better to specify).

Answer (score 0):

```
You should put the variable definition outside the if statements to

      String decksize = "";
      String trucksize = "";
      if (rad30Deck.isSelected()) {
         decksize = "30mm Wide";
      } else if (rad32Deck.isSelected()) {
         decksize = "32mm Wide";'
      } else {
         decksize = "33.3mm Wide";
      }

  if (rad30Trucks.isSelected()){
       trucksize = "30mm Wide";
   } else{
       trucksize = "32mm Wide";
   }
```